# How do I wire up a 4-wire light switch when I only have 3 wires from the wall?

Tags: electrical, wiring, installation

I am upgrading my light switches in a couple of places in my house. I opened up one wall and there are the typical 2 hot (black) wires and 1 ground (green) wire coming from the wall.

My light switch I am trying to install has 1 ground (green), 1 neutral (white) and 2 hot (black) wires.

So my question is, what are the correct connections for the wiring?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There have gotta be more wires in the back of the junction box.   It's very important to see them all and how they're grouped, i.e. They typically come into the box in several **cables** of black, white, ground and sometimes red wires.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box?

Comment: In a three switch circuit, sometimes known as a 4-way, only one of the three switches is actually a 4-way switch. The other two switches are typical 3-way switches.